Postgres: Can SQLState 08007 transaction_resolution_unknown happen?
I'm writing retry logic for handling various exceptions that can arise interacting with PostgreSQL using JDBC. I want to retry for some exceptions but not for others, based on the SQL state (error code) of the exception. According to the docs there is an error code 08007 | transaction_resolution_unknown. That sounds like something I would potentially not want to do a retry on.
I searched the PostgreSQL and pgjdbc source code expecting to find out what circumstances could give rise to the error code 08007 | transaction_resolution_unknown, but found none.
So my question is can this error actually arise?

The "best" explanation of this SQLSTATE can be found on PostgresPro documentation The PostgreSQL server signaled that we cannot start, commit, or rollback the transaction https://postgrespro.com/docs/postgresql/14/ecpg-errors also there was a case reported on this subject but without any  possible cause or solution on postgresql.org https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/Pine.LNX.4.58.0803100747400.13361%40samba.crysberg.dk

However looks like an issue of concurrency/high latency/communication that could be retried.

I'd say that you don't have to introduce any special handling for this error code, because it is defined, but not used at all by the current PostgreSQL source. The error may be in the list only because it is defined by the SQL standard.

what is the method to check something like that?

To clarify a previous answer, taking advantage of the fact that PostgreSQL is an open source project we could clone it (current version) locally
git clone https://git.postgresql.org/git/postgresql.git

and verify the use of that error code in the source code itself (to know if it could occur), a common error code 08006 ERRCODE_CONNECTION_FAILURE appears multiple times in source
find postgresql -type f -exec grep -lw 'ERRCODE_CONNECTION_FAILURE' {} \; 
           
postgresql/src/backend/utils/error/elog.c
postgresql/src/backend/utils/errcodes.txt
postgresql/src/backend/tcop/postgres.c
postgresql/src/backend/commands/subscriptioncmds.c
postgresql/src/backend/commands/copyfromparse.c
postgresql/src/backend/replication/logical/tablesync.c
8 more...

but 08007 ERRCODE_TRANSACTION_RESOLUTION_UNKNOWN by name or by code only appears in documentation files and one header file
find postgresql -type f -exec grep -lw '08007' {} \; 
                                 
postgresql/src/backend/utils/errcodes.txt
postgresql/src/interfaces/ecpg/ecpglib/ecpglib_extern.h
postgresql/doc/src/sgml/ecpg.sgml

find postgresql -type f -exec grep -lw 'ERRCODE_TRANSACTION_RESOLUTION_UNKNOWN' {} \;

postgresql/src/backend/utils/errcodes.txt

So could be concluded that is not used, only documented in compliance with the SQL standard.
